# Where can I get a dataset of URLs of websites that diffuse malware?

Tags: malware, websites

In order to study some malware detection algorithms I am developping in my PhD, I would like to know where I could download a list of malware websites.

Thank you

Comment: My question was about malware URL list while the question you pointed me to is about samples. Here is an answer http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/32058/looking-for-url-blacklists-of-malicious-websites